# Alignment of decimal points in an equation environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I've just returned to Latex after a break of nearly twenty years and I'm struggling a bit. Within an {align*} I have a list of numbers that need their decimal points aligned vertically. The following code snippet illustrates my difficulty.
I can find plenty of help for decimal alignment in a tabular environment but nothing that seems to match my problem. I've bodged the issue at the moment by inserting extra spaces, but I really don't want to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3\\
  \text{where}\\
  a_1 &= 1.23\\
  a_2 &= -4.56\\
  a_3 &= 78.90
\end{align*}

%failed attempt at aligning the decimal points

\begin{align*}
  y &= a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3\\
  \text{where}\\
  a_1 &= 1&.23\\
  a_2 &= -4&.56\\
  a_3 &= 78&.90
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output is shown below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried an array? `siunitx` should ring a bell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to align the equals signs in the main equation with those of the bottom block, because they're independent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
y = a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}}l<{{}} @{} S[table-format=-1.2] @{}}
  a_1 &= &  1.23\\
  a_2 &= & -4.56\\
  a_3 &= & 78.90
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The `S` column is not really necessary if the number of decimal digits is the same for all entries and `r` would suffice.

[image]

If you prefer smaller vertical space, use `gather*` and `\shortintertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
y = a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}}l<{{}} @{} S[table-format=-1.2] @{}}
  a_1 &= &  1.23\\
  a_2 &= & -4.56\\
  a_3 &= & 78.90
\end{array}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y &= a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3
\shortintertext{where}
a_1 &=\makebox[\widthof{$-4.56$}][r]{$1.23$}\\
a_2 &=-4.56\\
a_3 &=\makebox[\widthof{$-4.56$}][r]{$78.90$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't waste so much space, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
y = a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3
\end{equation*}
where $a_1 = 1.23$, $a_2 = -4.56$ and $a_3 = 78.90$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @EricTowers I was referring to the main equation with respect to the bottom block.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I've tried them all. 
(The only one I can't really use is the last because, in order to keep the question clear, I had simplified the polynomial. It's actually a six term Wagner style approximation with up to 8 digits after the decimal point. Stacking the coefficients is the only way to retain readability.)

Comment: @edmundb That's fair

Answer (score 7):

`alignat*` could be a possibility here. `\begin{alignat*}{2}` makes two `rl` column pairs with no space between them.

Note that I've used `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. `mathtools` loads and extends `amsmath`, providing among others `\mathrlap` and `\shortintertext`, both used here.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
y &= \mathrlap{a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3}\\
\shortintertext{where}
a_1 &= & 1  & .23\\
a_2 &= & -4 & .56\\
a_3 &= & 78 & .90
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, an `array` + `dcolumn`/`siunitx` would probably be easier.

Comment: The `\mathrlap` will break the centering if `fleqn` is not used.

Comment: @egreg True, good point. Thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 3):

Another, more compact, variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  y =a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3\\[2pt]
  \shortintertext{where\quad\smash{\rule[-6.2ex]{0.4pt}{7.5ex}}\enspace $ \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
        a_1 &= & 1 & .23\\
        a_2 &= & -4 & .56\\
        a_3 &= & 78 & .90
      \end{alignedat}$}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This surely doesn't work as-is with the UTF8 characters.

Comment: @Werner: As often, I copied the displayed code, instead of the saved one.  Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you'd like the conditions to be set in boxes that are the same width, all of which have their contents `r`ight-aligned. This is possible using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= a_1 x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3 \\
  \shortintertext{where}
  a_1 &= \eqmakebox[cond][r]{$ 1.23$} \\
  a_2 &= \eqmakebox[cond][r]{$-4.56$} \\
  a_3 &= \eqmakebox[cond][r]{$78.90$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` sets `<stuff>` in a box that has a specific `<align>`ment. All boxes with the same `<tag>` will be set to the width of the maximum `<stuff>` within that `<tag>`. The process involves usage of the `.aux`iliary file and there requires at least two compilation with any change of `<tag>` or `<stuff>`.