# Vertical aligning of numerical matrix elements on decimal point [LyX]

Tags: lyx, matrices, alignment

I have a Matrix with numerical entries in an Equation, like this

[image: This one]

I would like to align the entries at their decimal point, as in the Table.

Can this be done?

Edit:

The Matrix code is (from the .lyx file)

```
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1.2 & 34.5\\
-67.8 & 9.012
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end_inset
```

The relevant code for the Table is quite complicated due to the frame:

```
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="2">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="decimal" decimal_point="." valignment="top">
<column alignment="decimal" decimal_point="."   valignment="top">
<row>
<cell alignment="decimal" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
1.2
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="decimal" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
34.5
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="decimal" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
-67.8
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="decimal" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
9.012
\end_layout

\end_inset
```

Comment: see (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386425/alignment-of-decimal-points-in-an-equation-environment)]

Comment: Please show the underlying LaTeX code that generates the matrix and table.

Comment: @Mico: See the Edit.

Comment: @Denis, Thanks, I did not find this post. Does this solution need a manual edit in the .lyx file (by an external editor)? Or can the formatting of the array-envitoment be done within the LyX user interface?

Comment: See the answer by matea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the intended result by splitting each column into two, separated by a period in between:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Matrix
    \begin{equation}
        M = \left(
        \begin{array}{r@{.}lr@{.}l}
            1&2     &   34&5    \\
            -67&8   &   9&012   \\
        \end{array}
        \right)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: produced output]

Comment: Thanks. I edited the .lyx source code, and your solution worked nicely! 
My main .lyx document is about 800000 lines long. And I hesitate to manually edit the source code.
Do you know how to do this type of LaTeX array formatting within the LyX user interface?

Comment: Thanks. Of all solutions, I regard this approach the closest to the original LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

With libraries `amsmath` and `siunitx` of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
M = \begin{+pmatrix}[colspec={S[table-format=-2.1]@{}S[table-format=-2.3]}]
1.2   & 34,5    \\
-67.8 & 9.012   \\
    \end{+pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you. As you may read in my comment to matea, I would like to perform this formatting within LyX itself.

Comment: Table code for LyX should be the same. Since I don't use it, I can't help you with its editors specific. BTW, instead of "thank you" you can (according to size policy) upvote answer(s).

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe, you may consider to ask new question about how to integrate any LaTeX code found on this site  into LyX environments.

Answer (score 3):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and the columns `S` of `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
M = \begin{pNiceArray}{S[table-format=-2.1]@{}S[table-format=-2.3]}
1.2   & 34,5    \\
-67.8 & 9.012   \\
    \end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs a basic `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}
\[
M=\left(
\begin{array}{@{} S[table-format=-2.1] S[table-format=2.3] @{}}
   1.2 & 34.5   \\
 -67.8 &  9.012
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```